# Download XML using Powershell without WebClient

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a powershell script that has to download an xml file from a webserver.
The problem is that I can't use WebClient.Downloadstring since I first have to navigate to a login form and put my credentials.

Login is handled via a java applet, so if I use NetworkCredentials it doesn't work.

The only way I found out it is to create an InternetExplorer object and navigate to the login url, put the credentials and simulate a click on the submit button.

Then navigate to the page I want and save to a file.

It works but the downloaded file is extremely huge since it's filled up with extra Spans and divs.

I hope there is a better way to do it.

Comment: The login probably sets a cookie that shows the server it has authenticated. You may be able to do as you have done for the login process and then extract the cookie from the browser and use it when you fetch the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the way to do it.

I added a header with the authetication:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient

$token =  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username+":"+$password ))
$client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $token")

$xml = $client.DownloadString("http://myurl")
```